# Best way to differentiate an array of indices vs a boolean mask

Tags: python, numpy

If I am given an array of indices but I don't know whether it is a regular index array or a boolean mask, what is the best way to determine which it is?

Comment: Check the datatype `arr.dtype`?

Comment: Why are you being given an array without being told how it should be used?

Comment: @barmar Because they are both frequently used and valid methods of array indexing. For example, the scikit-learn one-hot encoder has a parameter which can be either an index array or a boolean mask, and a parameter to say which it is would be redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the dtype, or iterate through and check if the values are not in the set `{True, False}` as well as checking if the values are not in the set `{0,1}`

Boolean masks must be the same shape as the array they are intended to index into, so that's another check.

But there's no hard and fast way to distinguish a priori whether an array of consisting of only values in `{0,1}` is one or the other without additional knowledge.